# Almalinux 8.8 Stuck at "Downloading packages"

Tags: reinstall, ipmi

I am trying to install AlmaLinux 8.8 via use IPMI. I tried several times but installer every time stuck at same step. At first I thought the problem was in the alma iso file so I downloaded the updated version 8.8 from the almalinux official page and tried again. this did not work.

I installed the proxmox iso file to see if the problem applies to almalinux 8.8 and it installed successfully. i think the problem applies to almalinux 8.8. when i check the logs i don't see any problem. what do you think is the problem?

logs;

[image: install screen]

[image: main logs]
[image: storage logs]
[image: program logs]

Comment: How long are you waiting until you declare it "stuck"?

Comment: @Kusalananda More than 7-8 hours